# I want to display the line with the highest metric. But nothing comes out for me

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This is my table

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Marsel | 22 |
| Lewis | 33 |
| Andrew | 23 |
| Harry | 45 |

I need to display Harry's name on the console with his age 45
'''

```
public class Main {

  public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\school.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Director");
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator iterator=sheet.iterator();

    
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();

        Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case NUMERIC:
                    list.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
    Double max=Collections.max(list);
    int ind=list.indexOf(max);

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(ind+1);
        Iterator cellIterator=row.cellIterator();
        System.out.println(row);
        while(cellIterator.hasNext())
        {
            XSSFCell cell=(XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType())
            {
                case STRING: System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()); break;
                case NUMERIC: System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());break;
                case BOOLEAN: System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue()); break;
            }
        }
    }

    }
}
'''
```

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger already? If you know the layout of your table, i.e. what column contains what data why are you using such a complex iteration scheme? I haven't used POI in a while but it should have methods to deal with cells and cell ranges more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can only walk an iterator once. If you want to find the row again, you would have to read the file again from the top. The iterator you are using already return false on `iterator.hasNext ()`. So the second loop will not be entered at all.

Comment: I tried to read the file again, but after running the code, endless code happens.

Comment: And together with the maximum value this comes out: Harry45.0<xml-fragment r="3" spans="1:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <main:c r="A3" t="s">
    <main:v>2</main:v>
  </main:c>
  <main:c r="B3">
    <main:v>24</main:v>
  </main:c>
</xml-fragment>

Comment: @Niemand You have extra debugging `System.out.println`s in your code which probably cause the output you see. But it seems like you have modified your code a bit, so I can't really tell what is happining any more.